# ip_tables kernel module used in CentOS 7 does not stop Source Network Address Translation When the POSTROUTING SNAT Chain Rule is Deleted

Tags: iptables

I configured a Linux server to have a secondary IP address and to use `iptables POSTROUTING` to perform source network address translation (SNAT) using the following commands.

```
ip addr add 10.11.195.99/25 dev eno3 

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -o eno3 -s 10.11.195.45 \
-d 239.168.45.222 -j SNAT --to 10.11.195.99:60003
```

This all works great such that `tcpdump` shows that the source IP address `10.11.195.45` is replaced with `10.11.195.99`. However, when I flush the `iptables POSTROUTING` chain rule using:

```
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -X
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F OUTPUT
```

and deleted the secondary IP address `10.11.195.99`

The SNAT does not stop when the chain rules are deleted or flushed. Using `tcpdump` I can see that the outgoing packets still have `10.11.195.99` as the source IP address.

After adding conntrack -D --src-nat, the source network address translation stopped. However, this causes subsequent iptables SNAT POSTROUTING chain rule added to not work. How do I get source network address translation to work again?

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the output of `ip route show`.

Comment: Here's an excerpt from my answer there which should apply to your case: `conntrack -D --src-nat` (from package `conntrack-tools`)

Comment: The conntrack delete command works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Change picture (whoever you are):  (1) If you are Rebecca, please merge your accounts.  (If you aren’t Rebecca,  how do you know what happened when she ran a command on her system?)  (2) When you edit a post, please put a ***description*** (summary) of the edit in the edit comment.  Do not copy the entire edit into the comment field.

Comment: My answer in the duplicate doesn't just give a command to run, it explains what's happening and why. So any flow created before a change in rules doesn't follow the new rules. *each* time those rules are changed, you can use again a conntrack command to remove the flow and force it to traverse again the rules because it's again a NEW state. Normally this doesn't matter much because the flow won't last. But if you keep flows up (eg: emitting a video stream) this will matter.